# How can I convert a .bin file to either assembly or C?

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, firmware, c

I have a `.bin` file *(It's a firmware belongs to a hardware (Cisco Access-Point) )*. All I need to do is modifying that `.bin` file.

As you know, `.bin` files aren't human readable. I need to convert it to either assembly or C *(to make it readable and also changeable)*. Any idea how can I do such a thing?

Noted that [this](https://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=286286192&softwareid=282463166&release=1.0.0.15) is the file I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of that archive is not a single file, and so it cannot be "converted" to assembly. It'd only appear as a very long list of literal `db` statements.

From a cursory look, the file starts with some kind of header indicating which part go where. The parts themselves appear to contain a complete file system, as well as some sort of checksum at the end of each file (block?).

Unless you know the following point, then you cannot make it *changeable*.

1. what the meta-structure of this single file is,
2. what the file structure of the `rootfs` is, and
3. how the checksum is calculated,

Plain "readable" could possibly be already out of your league.